# Why querystring after ajax call while using datatable checkboxes?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatable

I am trying to save the data by selecting multi checkboxes in datatables. But after ajax call in the submit click the the ajax not hitting success function. It is showing querystring along with the controller/action.Like following

```
https://localhost:44307/Leaves/Approval?leaveApproveDataTable_length=10&id%5B%5D=11
```

This is my js

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-Approve', function (e) {
            var form = this;            

            var rows = $(table.rows({
                selected: true
            }).$('input[type="checkbox"]').map(function () {
                return $(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).closest('tr').attr('leaveid') : null;
            }));                      

            rows_selected = [];
            $.each(rows, function (index, rowId) {
                console.log(rowId)
                // Create a hidden element 
                rows_selected.push(rowId);
                $(form).append(
                    $('<input>')
                        .attr('type', 'hidden')
                        .attr('name', 'id[]')
                        .val(rowId)
                );
            });

            var remarks = $('#Remarks').val();

            console.log($(this).closest('tr').attr('leaveid'));

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Leaves/LeaveApproval',
                data: { approveId: rows_selected, remarks: remarks },
                type: 'POST',
                processData: true,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    debugger;
                    if (result) {
                        window.location.href = "/Leaves/Approval";
                    }
                    else {                       
                        return result;
                    }
                },
                error: function () {                   
                }                
            });

        });
```

This is my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LeaveApproval(List<int> approveId, string remarks)
        {


                foreach (int id in approveId)
                {
                    var leave = await _context.Leaves.FindAsync(id);
                    if (leave == null)
                    {
                        return Json(new { success = false });
                    }
                    leave.Status = "Approved";
                    leave.Remarks = remarks;
                    leave.ApprovedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    _context.Update(leave);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


            }
                 return Json(new { success = true }); 
        }
```

Kindly help me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While returning from the controller replace:
return Json(new { success = true }); this line with
return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: This is not working for me still getting error for me while return Json